# PostgreSQL slow query over ranked

Tags: sql, postgresql, performance

I have a query that is running really slow for production (900ms and sometimes even 3-4 seconds)
The query is pretty simple and slow due to a big table but not for a slow server. I am running over Aurora RDS serverless. I am asking is there a better way to go. I only want to join between two tables with his most recent values. I use Rank ordering by created_at

```
SELECT t1.* From (select msv.*, rank() OVER ( PARTITION BY machine_setting_id ORDER BY msv.created_at DESC )
                  as ranked from machine_setting_values msv inner join tasks t on t.id = msv.task_id inner join machine_settings ms
                  on ms.id = msv.machine_setting_id where t.work_order_id = 777 ) t1 where t1.ranked = 1
```

This is the explain over the query. Any help to do it better? What am I doing wrong?

DDL + Indexes

```
//machine settings table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.machine_settings
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    key character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    name character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    type character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    unit character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    machine_id bigint,
    position_in_list integer,
    impact character varying(1024) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    offline boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    parameter_type integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    owner_uuid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT machine_settings_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT machine_id_to_key_constraint UNIQUE (machine_id, key),
    CONSTRAINT fkgwgt4t00xcqaqp5yp54ojvjqn FOREIGN KEY (machine_id)
        REFERENCES public.machines (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE INDEX machine_settings_key_idx
    ON public.machine_settings USING btree
    (key COLLATE pg_catalog."default" ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX owner_id_machine_settings_index
    ON public.machine_settings USING btree
    (owner_uuid ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

//Tasks table 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.tasks
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    item_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
    type integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    status integer NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    work_order_id bigint,
    owner_uuid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT tasks_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT uk_hlgan0jf8stp23qon7hfq3fbr UNIQUE (item_uuid)
)
CREATE INDEX owner_id_tasks_index
    ON public.tasks USING btree
    (owner_uuid ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
CREATE INDEX tasks_item_uuid_idx
    ON public.tasks USING btree
    (item_uuid ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

CREATE INDEX tasks_time_range_idx
    ON public.tasks USING btree
    (created_at ASC NULLS LAST, updated_at DESC NULLS FIRST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

//machine settings values table
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS public.machine_setting_values
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    value character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    machine_setting_id bigint,
    centerline_value character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    feedback_id bigint,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    status integer,
    task_id bigint,
    min_value character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    max_value character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    owner_uuid uuid,
    CONSTRAINT machine_setting_values_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
    CONSTRAINT fk3w46u5qq6vkgd1hji8aey1usk FOREIGN KEY (machine_setting_id)
        REFERENCES public.machine_settings (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION,
    CONSTRAINT machine_setting_values_feedback_id_fkey FOREIGN KEY (feedback_id)
        REFERENCES public.feedbacks (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
CREATE INDEX owner_id_machine_setting_values_index
    ON public.machine_setting_values USING btree
    (owner_uuid ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: [Edit] the question and add the DDL for all involved tables and all indexes on them.

Comment: Show the output of `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)`, not just `EXPLAIN`.

Comment: Thanks @stickybit for the hint

Comment: Thanks, @jjanes for the extra explain things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An index `on machine_setting_values (task_id)` might be your best bet.  That way you would not need to full scan machine_settigs_values to get the matching rows, you could use a nested loop instead.  But there is no way to know for sure it will work (especially because the estimates are quite far off, 1043 predicted versus 57 actual) without just trying it to see.

But if you haven't already, you should VACUUM ANALYZE all the tables involved before doing anything else.

Comment: Thanks again @jjanes I will make the vacuum analyze and try the index. I will let you know the results

Comment: I got a really big performance increase having the index. Have a good Sunday!